# Identifying Users that have ordered >= N Dollars for N Consecutive Months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to write a query that returns a result set of accounts that have ordered at least 250 dollars each month for six consecutive months. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC ('month',order_date)::date as order_month
       ,account_name
       ,account_id
       ,SUM(order_amount) as monthly_spend
FROM order_table
WHERE order_date::date >= current_date - interval '6 months'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: What does "ordered at least 250 for 6 consecutive months" really mean?  Does it mean 250+ in each month?  Does it mean an average of 250+ over the period?  A total of 250+ over the period?  Something else?  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: Please add an explanation of why your query isn't working as you expect

Comment: It's the former. Those that have ordered at least $250 dollars each month for the last six consecutive months. Not an average.

Answer (score 1):

> Those that have ordered at least $250 dollars each month for the last six consecutive months.

Aggregation comes to mind.  Let me also align the months with the calendar months (that seems like the most likely interpretation of "last six months").

The idea is to filter down to the months that are >= $250 and then be sure there are six of them.

```
SELECT account_name, account_id, COUNT(*) as num_months,
      SUM(monthly_spend) as total_spend
FROM (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', order_date)::date as order_month,
             account_name, account_id, SUM(order_amount) as monthly_spend
      FROM order_table
      WHERE order_date::date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '6 months' AND
            order_date::date <  date_trunc('month', current_date)
      GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
      HAVING monthly_spend >= 250
     ) ma
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 6;
```

Comment: Same idea as I would of gone with as long as 'N consecutive months in the last N months' is using the same value for N. If it was 6 months consecutive in the last 12. Op hasn't made that clear but did not use the term 'last' in the current question, only the comment - makes me suspicious on the requirements.

Comment: @13ISPaulGeorge: BTW, assuming `order_date` is a `timestamp`, the cast in `order_date::date` isn't  achieving anything, but prevents the use of indexes. Remove it.

Comment: @Andrew . . . The `WHERE` clause seems to suggest that it is the last six months.